# Como aumentar tamanho do texto do AlertDialog?

Tags: android, dialog

Tem como aumentar o tamanho das letras de uma mensagem que exibo dentro de um `AlertDialog`?

Código:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);

builder.setMessage("Gasolina");
builder.setTitle("Sua melhor opção é:");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK",null);
builder.show();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use esse código abaixo para alterar o tamanho do texto:

```
AlertDialog dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle("Gasolina")
        .setMessage("Sua melhor opção é: ")
        .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
        .show();

        TextView textView = (TextView) dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
```

Comment: adicionei o code a pergunta

Comment: Denis, alterei a minha resposta com o código correto pra vc usar.